# Vue, filter property on Observable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm pretty new to Vue, what I'm doing now is the following.

I receive an *Item* prop in my component, I spread this *Item* prop out over a *Form* data object that's defined in my component (as to have reactivity)

```
data() {
  return {
    form: {}
  }
mounted () {
  this.form = {
    ...this.item,
    translations: { ...this.item.translations }
  }
},
```

Now my local form data holds the information, including reactive translations, right?

Next thing I try to do is filter this data, but then it's failing me.
If I console.log(this.form). It is an *Observable* (see screenshot)

[image]

Is there a way to filter, reduce, map on this 'Observable'?
Am I doing 'reactivity' the right way?

Comment: Can you show the code that filters the data? How is it "failing" you? An error message? Or unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clone/deepClone, before assigning the item to this.form.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `props` from `data()` directly.

```js
data() {
  return {
    form: {
      ...this.item,
      translations: { ...this.item.translations }
    }
  }
},
computed: {
   getForm() {
     // use filter/map method here, e.g.
     // return this.form.filter((item) => { ... })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that's a bit cleaner code, however the problem that I'm not able to fiter, reduce or work with that observable persists, any idea's?

Comment: You can filter/reduce/etc. in `computed:` property.. it is alos Reactive.

Comment: @SajibKhan `form` is not an `Array`, so it does not have a `filter` method.

Comment: yes, It was an sample example, it means you can do any operations on `this.form` inside computed: -> getForm() method.